# NetworkSteam Read without Write

Tags: c#, networkstream

So I'm writing an application in where I need to steam data from a client to my server and I've noticed some very weird behavior with how the `NetworkStream.Read` function behaves. I'm sending packets of about 18 bytes in length and if I make the while loop in the server Read and then Write then I get all of the packets properly. However, if I only Read and never Write then the Read does not return after a single packet. Instead, it gathers several packets before returning, saying that it received some 300+ bytes at each iteration. Does anybody know why I'm getting this behavior? I could simply write back 'a' every time but this seems a bit ghetto.

Here is the section of code:

```
    private static void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                // Block until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                // A socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                // The client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            Debug.print("Number of bytes: {0:D}", bytesRead);
            count++;

            // Message has successfully been received. Echo back.
            clientStream.Write(new byte[2], 0, 1);

        }
        Debug.print("Count: {0:F}", count);

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

Comment: TCP is a byte-stream, there are no packets.

Comment: ..Which means you need to handle sending/receiving packets yourself if you want this, and that means you must be prepared to receive partial packets/multiple packets.

Comment: But the function returns properly after receiving one packet of data when I use Write back?